# How to make the output of "git diff-tree -m ..." more succinct

Tags: git

If I run the following script in the terminal:

```
git init repo
cd repo
echo "bla" > e.log
git add .
git commit -m "init"
git checkout -b b1
echo "xxx" > x.log
git add .
git commit -m "added x"
git checkout -b b2 main
echo "yyy" > y.log
git add .
git commit -m "created y"
git merge --no-commit b1
rm -f x.log y.log
git commit -am "removed x and y"
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

I get a repo with this graph:

```
*   cc5e9ad (HEAD -> b2) removed x and y
|\  
| * adfb0a5 (b1) added x
* | 486672c created y
|/  
* 0ed638b (main) init
```

Now, if I run `git diff-tree -m --pretty=oneline b2` I get this output:

```
cc5e9ad24afe95b5ae1480aa6bc1f8aa53881760 (from 486672c8e28be6f4a8dfff8aa3c80203f1181510) removed x and y
:100644 000000 0b20aead00e76e9afc1ee8775b2705c77e790cf6 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  y.log
cc5e9ad24afe95b5ae1480aa6bc1f8aa53881760 (from adfb0a57d2c296f58c4b32e03affeb7fdb34c2ea) removed x and y
:100644 000000 d6459e005434a49a66a3ddec92279a86160ad71f 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  x.log
```

Is there a way to pass Git some output format option to get the next more succinct output?

```
486672c8e28be6f4a8dfff8aa3c80203f1181510
:100644 000000 0b20aead00e76e9afc1ee8775b2705c77e790cf6 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  y.log
adfb0a57d2c296f58c4b32e03affeb7fdb34c2ea
:100644 000000 d6459e005434a49a66a3ddec92279a86160ad71f 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  x.log
```

I am using git version 2.33.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
git diff-tree --pretty=oneline -m b2 \
| awk '!/^:/{$0=$4} 1' FS='[ ()]'
```

"on lines not starting with a colon, replace the whole line with its fourth field; and do the default print action on every line by testing a constant 1 condition, with space and parens counting as field separators".

Comment: This gives the output that I want, but I am looking for a single Git command. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @mljrg in service of what? Why should the people who write and maintain Git duplicate what the people who write and maintain awk have already done?

Comment: Well the people who develop Git are already duplicating existing functionality, for example, all the output formatting options Git offers. What I am looking for is simply some formatting option that can produce the output I want. Just that, one other formatting option. I believe my question was clear that I wanted just a Git-only solution, but sorry if it was not and I made you waste your time.

Comment: Well, if you want to build a house with just one tool, I suppose that might be an academically-novel exercise but I doubt it's going to get many people signing on to help with the effort. Is there some point to this beyond entertainment? Because right now your restriction is apparently self-imposed, fabricated and arbitrary. Maybe if you explained the point here? Is there perhaps some quiet part to the point that can't be said out loud? Seriously, I mean it: what exactly is your problem here?

Comment: There is no problem. I just wanted to know if there was the needed output option in Git, to avoid to parse the output via other means. In short, Git does not support this output, so I have to parse by other means, like as you suggested.